# What's the difference between =delete for templates and just using explicit?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

I was reading [Explicitly defaulted and deleted special member functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicitly_defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions), and saw that in order to call only the function `f` with `double` and avoid an implicit conversion, one could write this ([from the same page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicitly_defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions)):

```cpp
struct OnlyDouble
{
    void f(double d);
    template<class T> void f(T) = delete;
};
```

Is there a reason why one would write the code above instead of this code below?

```cpp
struct OnlyDouble
{
    explicit void f(double d);
};
```

Any difference, or is there some extra behavior that I don't know of?

Comment: The second snippet doesn't compile....

Comment: `explicit` isn't doing what you think.  It only works on _constructors_, and your member function `f` is not a constructor.  `f` - in your second example - still allows its parameter `d` to be implicitly converted from whatever can be implicitly converted to `double`, e.g., `f(1.3f)` and `f(17)` would still both work.

Comment: In the first code, `f()` can only be called with a `double` specifically, any other type will produce an error.  In the second code (if it compiled), `f()` can be called with any type that is convertible to `double`. You can use `explicit` only on constructors, conversion operators, and deduction guides, and `f()` is none of those.

Comment: Thanks. Could someone write an answer so that I can accept and upvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. `explicit` is not valid for functions so the `explicit void f(double);` doesn't compile.
2. `explicit` doesn't prevent implicit conversions of arguments.

That is, even if the comparison were between:

```cpp
struct OnlyDouble
{
    OnlyDouble(double d);
    template<class T> OnlyDouble(T) = delete;
};
```

and

```cpp
struct OnlyDouble
{
    explicit OnlyDouble(double d);
};
```

You're right that both would error on:

```cpp
OnlyDouble od = 42;
```

but following is ill-formed for the first and well-formed for the second:

```cpp
OnlyDouble od(42);
```

Comment: What then does `explicit` do in point `2` if it is doesn't prevent implicit conversions?

Comment: @heretoinfinity: It prevents implicit call to **constructor**.

Comment: @heretoinfinity In a single argument case, `explicit` prevents implicit conversion from an argument to the type directly. For example, given `void foo(OnlyDouble);`, `foo(42)` requires implicit conversion of `42` to `OnlyDouble`. `explicit` prevents that conversion. In a multi-argument case, it prevents brace-init-lists from being passed as arguments. For example, given `struct S { explicit S(int, int); };` and `void foo(S);`, `foo({1, 2})` is ill-formed with `explicit` but is well-formed without.